# Implementation of BIP-39 using C

Tags: c, cryptocurrency

I'm asking for anyone to review [my code](https://github.com/ciwise/bip39c)   and provide comments here. The code has a header file but I'll show the c module here. I haven't written any C code since probably before the year 2000. I'm a Java guy. This code will be used on a Linux server by Php code on a web server (Apache). Tell me what you think. Give me a code review. :-)

```
/* bip39c.c
 * A BIP-39 Implementation using C.
 * 
 * Generation of mnemonic words to be used to create 
 * a seed for the creation of private keys to be used 
 * with the implementation of a deterministic (seeded)
 * bitcoin wallet.
 * 
 * written by: David L. Whitehurst
 * date: May 30, 2018
 * 
 * Algorithm:
 * 1. Create a random sequence (entropy) of 128 to 256 bits.
 * 2. Create a checksum of the random sequence by taking the
 *    first (entropy-length/32) bits of its SHA256 hash.
 * 3. Add the checksum to the end of the random sequence.
 * 4. Split the result into 11-bit length segments.
 * 5. Map each 11-bit value to a word from the predefined
 *    dictionary of 2048 words.
 * 6. The mnemonic code is the sequence of words.
 *
 * Worksheet:
 * 1. 256 entropy bits + checksum 8 bits = 264 bits and 24 mnemonic 
  words
 *  
 */
#include "bip39c.h"

/*
 * The main function calls the generate method to output a random set of
 * mnemonics per BIP-39
 */

int main(int argc, char **argv) //*argv[])
{
    char *evalue = NULL; // entropy value
    char *kvalue = NULL; // mnemonic

    int c;

    if (argc == 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-e] [128, 160, 192, 224, or 256] [-k] [\"mnemonic mnemonic ... \"]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "e: k:")) != -1) {

        switch (c) {

            case 'e': // entropy set
                evalue = optarg;

                /* convert string value to long */
                long entropyBits = strtol(evalue, NULL, 10);

                /* actual program call */
                generate(entropyBits);

                break;

            case 'k': // seed key derived from mnemonic
                kvalue = optarg;
                pbkdf2_hmac_sha_512(kvalue);
                break;

            case '?':
                if (optopt == 'e' || optopt == 'k')
                    fprintf(stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
                else if (isprint(optopt))
                    fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
                else
                    fprintf(stderr,
                            "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n",
                            optopt);
                return 1;

            default:
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/*
 * This function checks to see if an input exists in an array
 */

bool isvalueinarray(int val, int *arr, int size){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == val)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/*
 * The function that generates the mnemonics. Only bit sizes 128, 160, 192, 224,
 * and 256 may be used for entropy per BIP-39
 */

int generate(int entropysize) {

    int ENTROPY_ARRAY[5] = { 128, 160, 192, 224, 256 };

    bool result = isvalueinarray(entropysize, ENTROPY_ARRAY, 5);

    if (result != true) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Only the following values for entropy bit sizes may be used: 128, 160, 192, 224, and 256\n");
    } else {

        int bytesOfEntropy = entropysize/8;
        int addChecksumBytes = entropysize/32;
        bool chk = getMnemonic(bytesOfEntropy,addChecksumBytes);

    }
    return 0;
}

/*
 * The function called by generate that implements the BIP-39 algorithm.
 * The data integer is the multiple that maintains our entropy. The mnemonic must
 * encode entropy multiple of 32 bits hence the use of 128,160,192,224,256.
 *
 * Next, each entropy bit size will require entropy-bits/8 entropy byte counts
 * hence the use of 16,20,24,28,32.
 *
 * The CS values below are the number of checksum bits that are added to the
 * entropy bytes prior to splitting the entire random series (ENT+CS) of bytes
 * into 11 bit words to be matched with the 2048 count language word files. The
 * final output or mnemonic sentence consists of (MS) words.
 *
 * CS = ENT / 32
 * MS = (ENT + CS) / 11
 *
 * |  ENT  | CS | ENT+CS |  MS  |
 * +-------+----+--------+------+
 * |  128  |  4 |   132  |  12  |
 * |  160  |  5 |   165  |  15  |
 * |  192  |  6 |   198  |  18  |
 * |  224  |  7 |   231  |  21  |
 * |  256  |  8 |   264  |  24  |
 */

int getMnemonic(int entBytes, int csAdd) {

    int ENTROPY_BYTES[5] = { 16, 20, 24, 28, 32 };
    int ENTROPY_BIT_SIZE = entBytes * 8;

    bool result = isvalueinarray(entBytes, ENTROPY_BYTES, 5);


    if (result != true) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Only the following values for the number of entropy bytes may be used: 16, 20, 24, 28, and 32\n");
    } else {

        /*
         * ENT (Entropy)
         */

        unsigned char entropy[entBytes];
        char entropyBits[ENTROPY_BIT_SIZE + 1];
        entropyBits[0] = '\0';

        char binaryByte[9];
        char segment[133] = { "" };

        int rc = RAND_bytes(entropy, sizeof(entropy));

        int i;
        for (i=0; i< sizeof(entropy); i++) {
            char buffer[3];
            memcpy( buffer, &entropy[i], 2 );
            buffer[2] = '\0';
            unsigned char *byte = hexstr_to_char(buffer);
            sprintf(binaryByte, BYTE_TO_BINARY_PATTERN, BYTE_TO_BINARY(*byte));
            binaryByte[8] = '\0';
            strcat(entropyBits, binaryByte);
        }

        /*
         * ENT SHA256 checksum
         */

        static char checksum[65];
        char entropyStr[sizeof(entropy)*2 + 1];
        sha256(entropyStr, checksum);
        char hexStr[3];
        memcpy(hexStr, &checksum[0], 2);
        hexStr[2] = '\0';

        /*
         * CS (Checksum portion) to add to entropy
         */

        switch (csAdd) {

            case 4: {
                produceMnemonicSentence(133, 5, hexStr, entropyBits);
                break;
            }

            case 5: {
                produceMnemonicSentence(166, 6, hexStr, entropyBits);
                break;
            }

            case 6: {
                produceMnemonicSentence(199, 7, hexStr, entropyBits);
                break;
            }

            case 7: {
                produceMnemonicSentence(232, 8, hexStr, entropyBits);
                break;
            }

            case 8: {
                produceMnemonicSentence(265, 9, hexStr, entropyBits);
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
     }

    return 0;
}

/*
 * This function prints the word found in the language file at the
 * particular line number given.
 */

void printWord(long lineNumber) {
    FILE *file = fopen("/usr/local/data/english.txt", "r");

    bool copy_characters = false;

    int line_number = 1;

    for (;;) {
        int c = fgetc(file);
        if (EOF == c) {
            break;
        } else if ('\n' == c) {
            ++line_number;
            if (lineNumber == line_number) {
                copy_characters = true;
            } else if (copy_characters) {
                break;
            }
        } else if (copy_characters) {
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}

/*
 * This function converts a null terminated hex string
 * to a pointer to unsigned character bytes
 */

unsigned char *hexstr_to_char(const char* hexstr)
{
    size_t len = strlen(hexstr);
    size_t final_len = len / 2;
    size_t s = sizeof(unsigned char*);
    unsigned char *chrs = (unsigned char *) malloc((final_len + 1) * sizeof(*chrs));
    size_t i, j;

    for (i = 0, j = 0; j < final_len; i += 2, j++)
        chrs[j] = (hexstr[i] % 32 + 9) % 25 * 16 + (hexstr[i + 1] % 32 + 9) % 25;
    chrs[final_len] = '\0';
    return chrs;
}


/*
 * This function prints an array of unsigned character bytes
 */

void printUCharArray(unsigned char bytes[], int size) {
    printf("0x");
    char str[size*2 + 1];

    int j;
    for(j=0;j< size;j++) {
        sprintf(&str[j*2], "%02x", bytes[j]);
    }

    printf("%s\n", str);
}

/*
 * This function implements a SHA256 checksum from a hex
 * string and loads a string of fixed length (hex string
 * of 64 chars or 32 bytes)
 */

int sha256(char *string, char outputBuffer[65])
{
    unsigned char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    SHA256_CTX sha256;
    SHA256_Init(&sha256);
    SHA256_Update(&sha256, string, strlen(string));
    SHA256_Final(hash, &sha256);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        sprintf(outputBuffer + (i * 2), "%02hhX ", hash[i]);
    }

    outputBuffer[64] = 0;
    return 0;
}


/*
 * This function prints the mnemonic sentence of size based on the segment
 * size and number of checksum bits appended to the entropy bits.
 */

int produceMnemonicSentence(int segSize, int checksumBits, char *firstByte, char entropy[]) {

    unsigned char *bytes;

    char segment[segSize];
    memset(segment, 0, segSize*sizeof(char));

    char csBits[checksumBits];
    memset(csBits, 0, checksumBits*sizeof(char));

    bytes = hexstr_to_char(firstByte);

    if (checksumBits == 5) {
        sprintf(csBits, BYTE_TO_FIRST_FOUR_BINARY_PATTERN, BYTE_TO_FIRST_FOUR_BINARY(*bytes));
    }
    if (checksumBits == 6) {
        sprintf(csBits, BYTE_TO_FIRST_FIVE_BINARY_PATTERN, BYTE_TO_FIRST_FIVE_BINARY(*bytes));
    }
    if (checksumBits == 7) {
        sprintf(csBits, BYTE_TO_FIRST_SIX_BINARY_PATTERN, BYTE_TO_FIRST_SIX_BINARY(*bytes));
    }
    if (checksumBits == 8) {
        sprintf(csBits, BYTE_TO_FIRST_SEVEN_BINARY_PATTERN, BYTE_TO_FIRST_SEVEN_BINARY(*bytes));
    }
    if (checksumBits == 9) {
        sprintf(csBits, BYTE_TO_BINARY_PATTERN, BYTE_TO_BINARY(*bytes));
    }

    csBits[checksumBits - 1] = '\0';

    strcat(segment, entropy);
    strcat(segment, csBits);
    segment[segSize - 1] = '\0';

    char elevenBits[12] = {""};

    int i;
    int elevenBitIndex = 0;
    for (i=0;i<segSize;i++) {

        if (elevenBitIndex == 11) {
            elevenBits[11] = '\0';
            long real = strtol(elevenBits, NULL, 2);
            printWord(real);
            printf(" ");
            elevenBitIndex = 0;
        }

        elevenBits[elevenBitIndex] = segment[i];
        elevenBitIndex++;
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

/*
 * This function performs the hash-stretching function PBKDF2 for BIP- 
   39
 */

 void pbkdf2_hmac_sha_512(const char* pass)
{
    char HexResult[128];
    memset(HexResult, 0, 64);

    unsigned int i;
    unsigned char digest[64];
    unsigned char salt[] = { 0x6d, 0x6e, 0x65, 0x6d, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x69, 0x63 }; // mnemonic (no passphrase)
    PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(pass, strlen(pass), salt, strlen((const char*) salt), 2048, EVP_sha512(), 64, digest);

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(digest); i++)
        sprintf(HexResult + (i * 2), "%02x", 255 & digest[i]);

    printf("%s\n", HexResult);

}
```

Comment: Have you tested this code? It seems to have major errors in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>         fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-e] [128, 160, 192, 224, or 256] [-k] [\"mnemonic mnemonic ... \"]\n", argv[0]);
> ```

This usage message seems to be non-standard. I would interpret it under standard conventions as saying that there are four independent optional arguments, but since it's apparently an error to supply no arguments then clearly they're not all optional; and looking at the way they're used it seems that there are only two independent arguments. I think the usage message would be more standard if it were something closer to

```
Usage: %s -e bits
   or  %s -k "mnemonic mnemonic ..."
```

Although that doesn't communicate the complexity of the way it loops, allowing you to have an arbitrary sequence of `-e bits` and `-k "mnemonic ..."`. So maybe it should be

```
Usage: %s <-e bits | -k "mnemonic mnemonic ...">...
```

---

> ```
> bool isvalueinarray(int val, int *arr, int size){
>     int i;
>     for (i=0; i < size; i++) {
>         if (arr[i] == val)
>             return true;
>     }
>     return false;
> }
> ```

This is not very idiomatic, although more readable to a non-C-programmer than an idiomatic version:

```
bool isvalueinarray(int val, int *arr, int size){
    while (size-- > 0) {
        if (*arr++ == val) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

> ```
>     int ENTROPY_ARRAY[5] = { 128, 160, 192, 224, 256 };
>
>     bool result = isvalueinarray(entropysize, ENTROPY_ARRAY, 5);
> ```

This seems a bit heavyweight for such a simple test as

```
entropysize >= 128 && entropysize <= 256 && entropysize % 32 == 0;
```

especially as the `%` can be optimised to a bitwise operation `(entropysize & 31) == 0`.

---

> ```
>     if (result != true) {
> ```

Some people have allergic reactions to comparisons to `true` or `false`, especially in C. `if (!result)`.

---

> ```
>     } else {
>
>         int bytesOfEntropy = entropysize/8;
>         int addChecksumBytes = entropysize/32;
>         bool chk = getMnemonic(bytesOfEntropy,addChecksumBytes);
>
>     }
> ```

Um? `getMnemonic` sounds like a function which returns a mnemonic, but `bool` doesn't sound like the right type for a mnemonic, `chk` doesn't sound like a sensible name for a mnemonic, and in any case it is just discarded. At the very least this needs some name changes; I think it probably also needs some error handling.

Is there any reason for passing two values into `getMnemonic` when the second is guaranteed to be exactly a quarter of the first?

---

> ```
>     int ENTROPY_BYTES[5] = { 16, 20, 24, 28, 32 };
>     int ENTROPY_BIT_SIZE = entBytes * 8;
>
>     bool result = isvalueinarray(entBytes, ENTROPY_BYTES, 5);
>
>
>     if (result != true) {
>         fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Only the following values for the number of entropy bytes may be used: 16, 20, 24, 28, and 32\n");
> ```

This check has essentially already been done in `generate`. Maybe you should refactor them together and do it just the once.

---

> ```
>         unsigned char entropy[entBytes];
>         char entropyBits[ENTROPY_BIT_SIZE + 1];
>         entropyBits[0] = '\0';
>
>         char binaryByte[9];
>         char segment[133] = { "" };
> ```

That's a lot of apparently closely related variables with no comments. What's the relationship between them?

---

> ```
>        int rc = RAND_bytes(entropy, sizeof(entropy));
> ```

Is that from OpenSSL? It would have been easier to review with the header file... If it is from OpenSSL, where are you ensuring that the pool has been seeded?

---

> ```
>         for (i=0; i< sizeof(entropy); i++) {
>             char buffer[3];
>             memcpy( buffer, &entropy[i], 2 );
> ```

It seems that the last time round the loop this will read from uninitialised memory. If that's intentional, it should be clearly documented.

> ```
>             buffer[2] = '\0';
>             unsigned char *byte = hexstr_to_char(buffer);
> ```

Huh? `buffer` has been filled with random *bytes* from `entropy`, but this seems to assume that those bytes are all hex digits. A clear explanation of why you're doing this is required.

> ```
>             sprintf(binaryByte, BYTE_TO_BINARY_PATTERN, BYTE_TO_BINARY(*byte));
> ```

Again, easier to review with the header file, which is where I'm guessing that `BYTE_TO_BINARY_PATTERN` and `BYTE_TO_BINARY` are defined.

> ```
>             binaryByte[8] = '\0';
>             strcat(entropyBits, binaryByte);
> ```

Whoa! `strcat` in a loop is Not Good™. Keep track of where the end is and append directly.

Also, `strcat` doesn't do length checks. You need to be *very* sure that `ENTROPY_BIT_SIZE` is defined correctly, or to add runtime sanity checks.

---

> ```
>         static char checksum[65];
>         char entropyStr[sizeof(entropy)*2 + 1];
>         sha256(entropyStr, checksum);
> ```

Huh? This is just hashing uninitialised memory. It appears to be missing some kind of copying step.

---

> ```
>         /*
>          * CS (Checksum portion) to add to entropy
>          */
>
>         switch (csAdd) {
>
>             case 4: {
>                 produceMnemonicSentence(133, 5, hexStr, entropyBits);
>                 break;
>             }
>
>             case 5: {
>                 produceMnemonicSentence(166, 6, hexStr, entropyBits);
>                 break;
>             }
>
>             case 6: {
>                 produceMnemonicSentence(199, 7, hexStr, entropyBits);
>                 break;
>             }
>
>             case 7: {
>                 produceMnemonicSentence(232, 8, hexStr, entropyBits);
>                 break;
>             }
>
>             case 8: {
>                 produceMnemonicSentence(265, 9, hexStr, entropyBits);
>                 break;
>             }
>             default:
>                 break;
>         }
> ```

Or in other words:

```
        produceMnemonicSentence(csAdd * 33 + 1, csAdd + 1, hexStr, entropyBits);
```

---

> ```
> /*
>  * This function prints the word found in the language file at the
>  * particular line number given.
>  */
> ```

Why not read the file into memory once and then print multiple words from memory?

---

> ```
>     FILE *file = fopen("/usr/local/data/english.txt", "r");
> ```

Missing error handling.

---

> ```
> unsigned char *hexstr_to_char(const char* hexstr)
> {
>     size_t len = strlen(hexstr);
>     size_t final_len = len / 2;
>     size_t s = sizeof(unsigned char*);
>     unsigned char *chrs = (unsigned char *) malloc((final_len + 1) * sizeof(*chrs));
> ```

Should there be some error handling for the case `len % 2 == 1`?

`s` seems to be unused, left over from a buggy earlier version.

---

> ```
>     size_t i, j;
>
>     for (i = 0, j = 0; j < final_len; i += 2, j++)
>         chrs[j] = (hexstr[i] % 32 + 9) % 25 * 16 + (hexstr[i + 1] % 32 + 9) % 25;
> ```

The invocation `(x % 32 + 9) % 25` could use a comment.

---

> ```
> void printUCharArray(unsigned char bytes[], int size) {
>     printf("0x");
>     char str[size*2 + 1];
>
>     int j;
>     for(j=0;j< size;j++) {
>         sprintf(&str[j*2], "%02x", bytes[j]);
>     }
>
>     printf("%s\n", str);
> }
>
> ...
> int sha256(char *string, char outputBuffer[65])
> {
>     ...
>     for(i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
>     {
>         sprintf(outputBuffer + (i * 2), "%02hhX ", hash[i]);
>     }
> ```

Is there some potential to refactor and share code?

---

> ```
> int produceMnemonicSentence(int segSize, int checksumBits, char *firstByte, char entropy[]) {
>
>     unsigned char *bytes;
>
>     char segment[segSize];
>     memset(segment, 0, segSize*sizeof(char));
>
>     char csBits[checksumBits];
>     memset(csBits, 0, checksumBits*sizeof(char));
>
>     bytes = hexstr_to_char(firstByte);
>
>     if (checksumBits == 5) {
>         sprintf(csBits, BYTE_TO_FIRST_FOUR_BINARY_PATTERN, BYTE_TO_FIRST_FOUR_BINARY(*bytes));
>     }
>     if (checksumBits == 6) {
>         sprintf(csBits, BYTE_TO_FIRST_FIVE_BINARY_PATTERN, BYTE_TO_FIRST_FIVE_BINARY(*bytes));
>     }
>     if (checksumBits == 7) {
>         sprintf(csBits, BYTE_TO_FIRST_SIX_BINARY_PATTERN, BYTE_TO_FIRST_SIX_BINARY(*bytes));
>     }
>     if (checksumBits == 8) {
>         sprintf(csBits, BYTE_TO_FIRST_SEVEN_BINARY_PATTERN, BYTE_TO_FIRST_SEVEN_BINARY(*bytes));
>     }
>     if (checksumBits == 9) {
>         sprintf(csBits, BYTE_TO_BINARY_PATTERN, BYTE_TO_BINARY(*bytes));
>     }
> ```

Surely there's a more readable way of doing this?

---

> ```
>     csBits[checksumBits - 1] = '\0';
> ```

Doesn't `sprintf` already null-terminate its output strings?

> ```
>     strcat(segment, entropy);
>     strcat(segment, csBits);
>     segment[segSize - 1] = '\0';
> ```

And `strcat`?

---

> ```
>     char elevenBits[12] = {""};
>
>     int i;
>     int elevenBitIndex = 0;
>     for (i=0;i<segSize;i++) {
>
>         if (elevenBitIndex == 11) {
>             elevenBits[11] = '\0';
>             long real = strtol(elevenBits, NULL, 2);
>             printWord(real);
>             printf(" ");
>             elevenBitIndex = 0;
>         }
>
>         elevenBits[elevenBitIndex] = segment[i];
>         elevenBitIndex++;
>     }
> ```

Let's see if I've understood: `segment` is an array which contains only values `48` and `49`, corresponding to `'0'` and `'1'`? And you collect them in a string to parse that string as a binary number? Why not work with an array which contains only values `0` and `1`, and convert to a binary number using `<< 1` and `|`?

Comment: Peter, this makes me want to dance! ```if (!(entropysize >= 128 && entropysize <= 256 && entropysize % 32 == 0)) {``` Thanks for your review. It's been a while but I really do like C.

Answer (score 3):

- The loop variable should be declared inside the loop, like so:

  ```
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) { /* etc... */}
  ```

  Ditto for the other loops.
- `size` as the upper bound of a for loop over an array and the index itself should be an unsigned type.
- The early return in `isvalueinarray` creates a timing side channel, which needs to be kept in mind if you choose to repurpose this function for comparing secret buffers.
- `int sha256(char *string, char outputBuffer[65])` and `int getMnemonic(int entBytes, int csAdd)` can be `void` functions since they always return 0.
- In `produceMnemonicSentence` you can replace the repeated if statements with a switch/case statement.

Comment: I agree with all the comments but I'm a little stumped on the "unsigned type" reference. Is this because of little endian or big endian on target machines? Excuse my ignorance here but why is the unsigned type important?

Comment: @DavidWhitehurst `size_t` is an unsigned type - neither too narrow nor too width - for array indexing per the C standard.  There is little advantage to index with another type and insufficiencies/excessiveness when using another type.  Select situations may benefit with another type, yet `size_t` should be the first consideration.